# Installing custom pip libraries inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip

I am having problems with accessing my app inside Docker container. Basically I want to install it via *pip* inside the container and run main script that imports this package as dependency.

Here is `Dockerfile` main functionality:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY WasteClassifier /opt/WasteClassifier
RUN apt update && apt-get -y install sudo && sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages"
RUN python3 -m pip install --target="/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages" /opt/WasteClassifier
RUN python3 -c 'import WasteClassifier'
```

When running main script from the app I get the following import error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WasteClassifier'
```

Made additional step to print all the importables, where my app is listed, although I cannot import it in the same step, [here is screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mkbf.png).
Also it is listed in *pip* libs, [pip list screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDASZ.png).

App works correctly outside of container on Ubuntu.

What might be the problem here? Is it more like Python or Docker issue, where should I look?

I have tried exporting paths, changing installation paths, changing `sys.path` in Python, installing different *pip*s (`apt-get install pip` / `apt-get install python-pip`), using different Python and Ubuntu versions in the image, none of this works.

EDIT: Thank you for help, the solution was to reorganize app structure as @yong and @RobD said. Previously it was organized like:

```
WasteClassifier
|-- Dockerfile
|-- WasteClassifier
    |-- setup.py
    |-- WasteClassifier
        |-- module1
        |-- module 2
```

Now it is organized like:

```
WasteClassifier
|-- Dockerfile
|-- setup.py
|-- WasteClassifier
    |-- module1
    |-- module2
```

Don't know exact reason behind this, and I cannot analyze this right now. If someone is interested I can describe it in detail in a few days. Made also some changes in `setup.py` and `__init__.py`, so it might also impact the fix. Thank you for help guys

Comment: If `WasteClassifier` is a directory, please show its structure. And you can add `RUN python3 -m pip list` before `RUN python3 -c 'import WasteClassifier'` to check what modules installed.

Comment: If `apt-get install sudo` works than you don't need `sudo apt-get install` — `apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip` will work too.

Comment: Why the `PYTHONPATH` modification, and the use of the `--target` option for the installation with *pip*? Those are red flags to me, I would recommend to get rid of those, unless there is a good reason to use them. -- I recommend to create and use a Python virtual environment. Yes, even in a Docker container (especially since it is a `ubuntu` based image).

Comment: @yong pip lists it correctly, attached screenshot in an edit

Comment: @phd I had some problems with trying to install it the other way, this solution comes from them

Comment: @sinoroc this is best thing I could achieve in seeking the solution - without it result is the same, just inserted it here to make suree paths are correct and python actually sees them. Will try later today or tomorrow with virtual env

Comment: No screenshots of text or code! Copy-paste the text into the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the last three lines of your Dockerfile are equivalent to the simpler:

```
RUN python3 -m pip install /opt/WasteClassifier
RUN python3 -c 'import WasteClassifier'
```

And if that works no better (which I don't believe it will) then it's because `pip` installs a *package* called `WasteClassifier`, but that package does not contain a *module* called `WasteClassifier`. A pip distribution package is not the same as a module, even if it has the same name. So this is a packaging problem, and depends on the content of the `WasteClassifier` directory (as @yong implied).

If it appears to work outside Docker, then that's likely because there is something else in your development environment that defines the `WasteClassifier` module -- it could be something as simple as having the source code directly in your module path. Docker is very helpful at revealing hidden environmental dependencies.

Not relevant as it turns out but worth pointing out in case it saves you pain later:

If the problem did require you to set `PYTHONPATH` (or any other environment variable) then this formulation would not help:

```
RUN export PYTHONPATH="..."
RUN python3 -c 'import something'
```

Because each `RUN` command executes in a separate shell, and the environment of the first is invisible to the second. You would need to combine them into a single command, using this common idiom:

```
RUN export PYTHONPATH="..." && \
    python3 -c 'import something'
```

This can be a good thing anyway, as each extra `RUN` command adds an extra layer to your image which makes it more expensive to load.